# What is wp-includes in wordpress and the purpose of it?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to know what is the importance of wp-includes in wordpress

Comment: easiest google search, i've ever done.... https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74940/what-is-the-wordpress-wp-includes-folder-for

Comment: thanks you for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wp-includes is the directory that contains most of WordPress' main functionality. It's where all the major WordPress code lives.